# Dependency Injection framework for Windows 8 metro apps

Tags: dependency-injection, windows-8, microsoft-metro

i can't seem to find a dependency injection framework for windows 8 metro apps.

Is there a framework for win8 metro apps?

Ninject is not yet support for win8 metro. So does anybody have a suggestion? (Castle, Spring, ...)

Comment: What about http://metroioc.codeplex.com/ or http://nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.Container?

Comment: MEF was mentioned at //BUILD, so it should be supported

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the source for Ninject WinRT: https://github.com/remogloor/ninject
It just not yet released.

Comment: Do you know when it's going to be released?

Answer (score 6):

You could try [Unity 3.0 for .NET4.5 Preview](http://unity.codeplex.com/releases/view/75719).

Comment: Unity 3 is now part of Microsoft.Practices: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170416.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the Beta version of [Autofac Portable Library](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/list) (which is supported in Metro apps) and it is working great so far.

Answer (score 0):

The Catel MVVM toolkit also contains a DI-container, it's metro version will be released this week (according to one of their developers): http://catel.codeplex.com