# How to use DI with WinRT

Tags: xaml, mvvm, dependency-injection, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In a WinRT Page how can I inject dependencies?

I am thinking of doing something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// A page that displays an overview of a single group, including a preview of the items
/// within the group.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MyPage : NSyncApplication.WinRT.Common.LayoutAwarePage
{
    IMyDependency _myDependency;

    public MyPage(IMyDependency myDependency)
    {
        _myDependency = myDependency;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

If this isn't a good practice please explain and recommend an alternative solution.

Note:

I don't need the specific DI containers that can be used with WinRT, that's been answered already and any idiot can look at nuget gallery and pick their choice.

This question is about how I can plug into the Page factory and inject my own dependencies. I have also looked at Prism for WinRT and that thing is even more convoluted than I remember the WPF version to be.

To repeat:

1. How can I inject into the page directly. Is there a page factory
   or something that I can tap into to add custom instantiation code?
2. Should I inject to the code behind and make it a viewmodel? The Prism MVVM example had
   another layer of abstraction for the ViewModel separate from the
   code behind (which's considered part of the View). This is nice and cool, but requires more wiring and
   custom mark ups than I care to do for my relatively simple project. I am hoping to roll with something more "light-weight". But may be there's an argument to be made against that, please explain.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161661/dependencyinjection-on-winrt-pages & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969417/dependency-injection-framework-for-windows-8-metro-apps

Comment: This question is specifically asking **how to set up DI** as clearly stated with the words "how I can plug into the Page factory and inject my own dependencies". We now know NInject *can* do the necessary in WinRT, but that (although useful information) is not the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check MVVM-Light. They use VMLocator which exposes view models to which XAML can bind. On MSDN Magazine you can find an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx) of how to use it.